# How would I author a collection that ensures no two identical types appear in it?

Tags: java, list, collections, types

I want to create a set or a collection that have a set of items. Each item implements the interface `WeaponAccessory`. However, I don't want two items with the same `WeaponAccessory` type. So the list should never have two suppressors or two extended mags.

To make this clearer. Let's say that a class M16 has an instance variable of a collection of WeaponAccessories. How would I guarantee that this list will not include two objects from the same type(Two suppressors, or two extended mags)? All Accessories(suppressor, extended mags..etc.) are classes that implements `WeaponAccessory. So you can create a set or list of`WeaponAccessory but I want distinct types in it.

How would I go about writing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want an enumeration instead of an interface, which will give you the ability to meld this into a set with guaranteed uniqueness.

```
public enum WeaponAccessory {
    EXTENDED_MAGAZINE,
    SUPPRESSOR,
    THUMB_GRIP,
    ANGLED_GRIP
}
```

Using this then becomes a trivial matter of adding the specific type of weapon accessory you want to whichever weapon you wish.  I leave that portion as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: I cannot use enums because these accessories have their own functionalities that I want to use. Enums dont support that.

Comment: @MSOUFAN: You can absolutely create your own methods in an enum.  Nothing's stopping you from doing that.

Comment: So if I created the class M16 that has a collection of WeaponAccessory, I will not be able to add two SUPPRESSOR to that set or collection?

Comment: @MSOUFAN: That would be the responsibility of the M16 class to define.  The attachments shouldn't care if they're compatible with a certain gun. The guns absolutely should care what attachments are being used with it.

Comment: But yes, because you'd already have a suppressor in your set, you couldn't add multiples since the set would reject the duplicate.